# Difference between decimal and decimal.value?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I often have to call the Value property when accessing my Linq to SQL objects to check for null values or I get an exception.  Can someone please expain these data types (i.e. decimal?, bool?, etc...) that appear to wrap the primitive types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nullable integer in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735638/nullable-integer-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are Generics of type `Nullable<T>`, and they do wrap primitive types.

Why they invented the short form int? is Nullable seems to be down to the standard confusion between succinct and terse C based language developers struggle with.

```
decimal? total = null;
```

`total.HasValue` will return false, it won't blow up with a null reference

but `total.Value.ToString();` will throw an exception, because the `Value` property of total is null.

The `Value` and HasValue properties are read only.

```
total = 10;
```

means total.Value will return 10.0 and total.HasValue will return true.

It's a really nice generic, especially for database types, still don't get the short form though...

Answer (score 1):

`decimal?` is shorthand (and equivalent to) `nullable<decimal>`, which means it can have a value of `null` set to it. The same thing applies to `bool?`, `int?`, etc.

These values are chosen by Linq 2 SQL when your database fields allow null values. Otherwise, you would not have a way to indicate that those values should be `null`.